# Keyboard language resetting after every restart on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I have a problem with my keyboard language settings, on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

Everytime i start up my pc, the language settings for my keyboard are not applied correctly. The settings are correct in my terminal, but everywhere else it is using the english keyboard (I am using a danish keyboard layout). The way i can temporarily fix the problem, is by going into the keyboard settings and either adding or deleting a keyboard layout language. If i add a new user, the problem does not persist on the new user.

I have tried:
Writing a script that adds or deletes a keyboard layout everytime i start the pc. I did this through:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

This did not fix it.
I tried playing around with the language settings in Chromium,to see if it was a problem with the settings in each program (Since it works as intended in the terminal).

Checking my settings in "/etc/default/keyboard" on startup, which are:

```
XKBMODEL="pc104alt"
XKBLAYOUT="dk"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

I've also tried reconfiguring the keyboard layout through:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

By suggestion i also tried resetting my setting with:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/
```

Any new ideas would be greatly appreciated, even if it is a makeshift solution, like i tried with the script.

Comment: First try resetting the related dconf settings: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/`. Now change your keyboard setting and see whether it "sticks" this time.

Comment: Just tried it. It did not stick.

Comment: OK, add that to your question: it already eliminates one possible cause and others will not make the same suggestion if they see you already tried. Use "edit" to update your question.

Comment: That has been done. Thanks for the tips! It is greatly appreciated